# How to manually stop a watcher?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs3, watch

I need to stop `watch()` but the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#stopping-a-watcher) don't really explain how to do that.

This watcher runs until the loop is finished (1000 seconds):

```
const state = reactive({
    val: 0
})

watch(() => state.val, () => {
    console.log(state.val)
})

for (let i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    setTimeout(function timer() {
        state.val = state.val + 1
    }, i * 1000);
}
```

How do I stop the watcher after running once? Using `watchEffect` is not an option because for my use case the watcher needs to run several times before stopped, which is not described in this simplified example. From my understanding `watchEffect` runs only once (after initiation).

Answer (score 4):

The "watch" function returns a function which stops the watcher when it is called :

```
const unwatch = watch(someProperty, () => { });

unwatch(); // It will stop watching
```

To watch a change only once:

```
const unwatch = watch(someProperty, () => {
   // Do what your have to do

   unwatch();
});
```